# Time data to match strptime

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

First question and new to python coding

I am getting the error. Time data ‘75.5’ does not match format ‘%s.%f’ -

which I understand is due to seconds counting to above 59 however I presumed putting an if clause with %m would solve?

Firstly code scraps a string that is in second:microsecond format

```
leadtime = leadtime.replace(‘:’, ‘.’)
If leadtime != ‘’:
    Try:
    leadtime = datetime.strptime(leadtime, ‘%S.%f’)
    leadtime = leadtime.strftime(‘ %S.%f’)[:-4]
    Except ValueError:
    leadtime = datetime.strptime(leadtime, ‘%M.%S.%f’)
    leadtime = leadtime.strftime(‘ %M.%S.%f’)[:-4]
```

Suspect i need to convert when seconds are above 59 seconds but not sure how??

Comment: do you only have the seconds, no date, hour or minutes? if so, the values like 75.5 seem to be a `timedelta` to me

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with code in the except

```
leadtime = float(leadtime)
leadtime = leadtime * 1000 #conversion to microseconds
leadtime = datetime.fromtimestanp(leadtime/1000.0).strftime(‘%M.%S.%f’)[:-4]
```

Comment: why do you convert to microseconds if you need seconds (for `fromtimestamp()`)? also note that the datetime object you get will refer to the local time of your operating system (unless you provide a timezone).